# Show/Hide divs with priorities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got multiple divs with one or multiple classes each div. The classes can be `info`, `debug`, `init` or `auth`. Filters should hide or show these different classes.

**The challenge:**

`Info` and `Debug` have higher priorities than `Init` or `Auth`. So if we've got the following div: `<div class="info build">Info Build Text</div>` it should be hidden if the `info` filter is active, regardless what the `build` filter says.

**The problem demonstrated in a JSfiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/7od81x0t/
[image]

1. Uncheck one of the category checkboxes (Auth) -> All "Auth" Divs will disappear, which is correct
2. Uncheck the Log Level `Normal` -> All left "Info" Divs will disappear, which is correct so far
3. Check Auth again, all Auth divs will appear again (including those divs which also contain the info class). That is not correct because the log level should have a higher priority for hiding the visibility.

**My idea to solve this:**

I thought I could solve this by using the `!important` CSS property, until I saw that `show()` and `hide()` manipulate the dom element itself instead of the classes. Right now no decent way to solve this issue comes to my mind.

Comment: `!important` overrides even inline styles (at least on the major browsers we use)

Comment: @GoneCoding unless inline have important as well.

Comment: You can use the `:not(.info, .debug)` filter as I have given below

Comment: @YanMayatskiy: true but uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to cover these situations in much simpler terms by using CSS classes. Take [this](https://jsfiddle.net/h8uj1ost/1/) JSFiddle for example.

Essentially, you wrap everything you want with a parent `div`. E.g.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="info build">Info Build Text</div>
  <div class="info init">
    Info Init Text
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And then set up some CSS classes you can apply to this to hide things you want:

```
.hide-auth .auth,
.hide-init .init,
.hide-info .info,
.hide-debug .debug,
.hide-build .build {
  display:none;
}
```

And then your JavaScript simply becomes toggling the classes:

```
/* If any checkbox status has been changed */
$("#sidebar").children("input").on("change", function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $('#parent').toggleClass('hide-' + name, !this.checked);
    //var isTargetHidden = $("." + this.name).is(":visible");
});
```

To get the slide effect, you can use CSS transitions on the `max-height` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not(.info, .debug)` filter in the `else` block as below.

```
        else {
            if(this.checked)
                $("." + this.name + ':not(.info, .debug)').show(400);
            else
                $("." + this.name + ':not(.info, .debug)').hide(400);
        }
```

You can check the same below and also I have updated the same in the following fiddle link,

https://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/7od81x0t/1/

```js
    /* If any checkbox status has been changed */
    $("#sidebar").children("input").on("change", function() {
        var className = $(this).attr("class");

        // If we want to toggle the loglevel visibility we don't need to take care of other filtered values as this has priority
        if(className == "loglevel") {
            if(this.checked)
                $("." + this.name).show(400);
            else
                $("." + this.name).hide(400);
        }
        else {
            if(this.checked)
                $("." + this.name + ':not(.info, .debug)').show(400);
            else
                $("." + this.name + ':not(.info, .debug)').hide(400);
        }

        //var isTargetHidden = $("." + this.name).is(":visible");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info build">Info Build Text</div>
<div class="info init">
  Info Init Text
</div>
<div class="info init">
  Info Init2 Text
</div>
<div class="info init">
  Info Init3 Text
</div>
<div class="info auth">
  Info Auth Text
</div>
<div class="debug auth">
  Debug Auth Text
</div>
<div class="debug auth">
  Debug2 Auth Text
</div>
<div class="info auth">
  Info Auth Text
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="sidebar">
  <div>
    <strong class="title2">Log Level</strong>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="loglevel" name="info" checked="checked">
  <label for="info">Normal</label></br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="loglevel" name="debug" checked="checked">
  <label for="debug">Verbose / Debug</label>
  <div>
    <strong class="title2">Category</strong>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="init" checked="checked">
  <label for="init">Initializing Procedure</label></br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="auth" checked="checked">
  <label for="auth">Auth</label></br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your conditionals so that you always check the status of the `loglevel` checkboxes before the `.hide()` or `.show()`. That will make those the overriding condition. Something like this..

```
    /* If any checkbox status has been changed */
$("#sidebar").children("input").on("change", function() {
    var className = $(this).attr("class");

    // If we want to toggle the loglevel visibility we don't need to take care of other filtered values as this has priority
    if(className == "loglevel") {
        if(this.checked)
            $("." + this.name).show(400);
        else
            $("." + this.name).hide(400);
    }
    else {
        if(this.checked && $(".loglevel[name='debug']").is("checked"))
            $("." + this.name).show(400);
        else
            $("." + this.name).hide(400);
    }
});
```

Comment: Aternatively, you could use a `.filter()` and include both `.checked` statuses in the callback.